# Django models - Set an Foreign key attribute from a Many to Many in an antribute on the same level

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, many-to-many

AttributeError: type object 'type' has no attribute 'subtipos'

I know that isnt working cause the object attribute isnt declared before assigning the attribute subtipo.
I would like to know how to get a single subtipo to the Asset class selecting from the subtipos of the AssetType class.

```
class SubAssetType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)   



class AssetType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    subtipos = models.ManyToManyField(SubAssetType, blank=True)
    
   

        
class Asset(models.Model):
    # Atributos nominales
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Atributos de valor
    type = models.ForeignKey(AssetType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtipo = models.ForeignKey(type.subtipos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`type` is a reserved word in python, so you cant use it as a model's attribute. Try refactoring your `Asset` like maybe this?

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    # Atributos nominales
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Atributos de valor
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(AssetType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtipo = models.ForeignKey(type.subtipos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Even the stackoverflow syntax highlighter shows that the `type` line is different from the rest :)

Comment: Yes I know but that type is a reserved word, but I woud like to know if I can set the subtipo as a foreign key  with tipo.subtipos (ManytoMany)